# Sending attachment using AWS SNS(Simple Notification Service)

Tags: amazon-sns

I am using **AWS SNS** for sending alert emails. Now the email content is really **long** therefore I wish to send it as a **file attachment** rather than sending it as a email content. Can this be done using SNS ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it can't.

The [SNS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/) does not come out and explain this explicitly, but it can be inferred from several statements:

> Amazon SNS messages can contain up to 256 KB of text data, including XML, JSON and unformatted text.
>
> The ”Email” transport is meant for end-users/consumers and notifications are regular, text-based messages which are easily readable.

In addition, since you do not have access to the email header space when publishing to SNS, it is not possible to specify the necessary multipart coding for an email client to decide an embedded attachment.  You can't even send HTML emails (well, you *could*, but a standards-conforming email client would not render them as HTML).

Now, many email clients will theoretically recognize `http://...` in an email body and turn them into clickable links, allowing you to link to the desired file... but that of course is not the same thing as attaching files.

I there does not appear to be a mechanism for attaching files to emails in SNS.

Comment: Just in case someone needs, there is a separate AWS SES service for sending emails in which you can do file attachments.

Answer (score 0):

[Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214877/10871073) is correct.

---

As an alternative to SES, you can still use SNS.

---

In your SNS message, you can add a link to an object in S3, where you store the file, and the subscribers to the topic can access (as long as your S3 has proper permissions) the file that way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [a blog from 2011](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-simple-email-service-now-supports-attachments/), attachments can be appended to an SNS e-mail using the SDK.  In the linked blog, the author also added some PHP code which I copy here for completeness (no idea if this actually works):

> ```php
> #!/bin/env php <?php include(‘Mail/mime.php’); include(‘sdk.class.php’); Create a MIME message with text and HTML
> bodies, and a PDF attachment:
>
> $mail_mime = new Mail_mime(array(‘eol’ => “\n”));
> $mail_mime->setTxtBody(“Hello Jeff, here’s your invoice.\n”);
> $mail_mime->setHTMLBody(“<p>Hello Jeff, here’s your invoice.</p>”);
> $mail_mime->addAttachment(“/tmp/invoice.pdf”, “application/pdf”);
> Retrieve the complete message body in MIME format, along with the
> headers:
>
> $body = $mail_mime->get(); $headers =
> $mail_mime->txtHeaders(array(‘From’ => ‘jbarr@amazon.com’, ‘Subject’
> => “Invoice for Jeff”));
> ```

Comment: That blog's talking about the SES (Simple Email Service), not SNS isn't it?